# What does this Lisp code do?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

There are a large number of web site which praise Lisp but I came across this page https://matthias.benkard.de/journal/110 which has this code:

```
((lambda([])((lambda(|| |()| |(| |)|)(+ || |(| 1 |)| |()| |(| |(| |(|)) [] [] [] [])) 0)
```

What does this code do? I am reluctant to try this code myself without knowing what it actually does.

In the conclusion part, it is pointed out that the page was written on 1st of April, but does the above code do anything at all?

Comment: Hint: in CL `|)|` is the *symbol* of name `)` (a single character string containing a close parenthesis)

Comment: Can |)| be replaced by any other symbol, say sym?

Comment: Yes, in particular if `sym` is fresh (perhaps [gensym](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_gensym.htm)ed)

Answer (score 4):

Well this is a post joking about java and lisp, it has no sense and I think that with every language you can write weird code like this:

I personally like this with javascript:

```
 2016-07-11 15:08:33 ☆ |ruby-2.2.3@laguna| Antonios-MBP in ~
○ → node
> Array(16).join("lol" - 2) + " Batman!";
'NaNNaNNaNNaNNaNNaNNaNNaNNaNNaNNaNNaNNaNNaNNaN Batman!'
>
```

Going into the code but a little bit formatted:

```
((lambda ([])
   ((lambda (|| |()| |(| |)|)
      (+ || |(| 1 |)| |()| |(| |(| |(|))
    [] [] [] [])) 
  0)
```

for this we need to know two things about common lisp the sintaxis of the lambda function and a little bit about symbols sintaxis and variables:

first trick: [] is a variable name

```
CL-USER> (defparameter [] 2)
[]
CL-USER> (+ [] [])
4
```

second trick: you can put any name to a symbol within `|symbol-name|` so 
`(|| |()| |(| |)|)` so this are only the entry variables for the second lambda, finally, this lambdas have the body and the excution parameter for the first lambda is 0 and for the intern lambda four `[]`

So this can be rewriten as:

```
((lambda (a)
   ((lambda (x y z k)
      (+ x z 1 k y z z z))
    a a a a))
 0)
```

and finally is easy to guess that this will be one